# Printing WPF window to a PDF wirthout print dialogue

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing

Working on an app for creating purchase orders. I simply used a wpf window as the final document's template and I was originally using PrintDialog(), doing some adjustments to the scaling, then passing the grid of my window to PrintVisual() and went thru the dialog. However it doesn't work for my application as the final document needs to be saved to a specific director automatically without the users input. After much struggle trying to find a solution I have been able cobble this together:

```
 public void printChartsAsPrintDoc()
        {
            Grid datagrid = pOTemplate.g;
            try
            {
                RenderTargetBitmap rendertargetbitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)datagrid.ActualWidth, (int)datagrid.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                rendertargetbitmap.Render(datagrid);
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder bitmapencoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                bitmapencoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rendertargetbitmap));
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                bitmapencoder.Save(stream);
                System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                loadPOList(dt2 as System.Data.DataTable);
                string x = "test";
                if (tbDocumentNumber.Text != null)
                {
                    x = tbDocumentNumber.Text;
                }
                Directory.CreateDirectory(finalDocPath + docCount + "-" + x + " " + CurrentDocument.GetSendToContact().raw + "TESTING IGNORE" + @"\");
                PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
                {
                    PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                    {
                        PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",
                        Collate = true,
                        PrintToFile = true,
                        
                        PrintFileName = finalDocPath + docCount + "-" + x + " " + CurrentDocument.GetSendToContact().raw + "TESTING IGNORE" + @"\" + docCount + "-" + x + " " + CurrentDocument.GetSendToContact().raw + ".pdf",
                    }
                };
                doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; //or false!
                doc.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    System.Drawing.Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

                    if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
                    {
                        m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
                    }
                    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
                };
                doc.Print();
                WriteToBinaryFile<DocumentData>(@"C:\Users\Martin Janda\Desktop\docdata.dd", CurrentDocument);
                UpdatePOList();
                resetDoc();

                SendSupportEmail();

                MessageBox.Show("Document has been created.");
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Printing failed, please generate a document first." + ex);
                return;
            }
           

        }
```

However I am having issues getting the image to take up the entire PDF page, also the resolution doesn't look too great and the saddest part is that since I have to convert to an image in  order to have something I can actually pass to printDocument() so I can handle all the printing programmatically; text in the pdf is no longer selectable...

So I figured I'd ask here if anyone has any experience with stuff like this, wether it be how to force my bitmap to take up the whole pdf/or if theres a way to print the grid directly to pdf. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.
I have tried using pdfsharp (v 1.31) to convert to xml then xml to pdf but I was completely unable to get the thing to work as the only version that allows for this feature is old, and the code was full of errors that were impossible to resolve as there were straight up nonexistent names, like XImage.

Comment: You can improve image size and resolution, instead of manipulating the image size in the PrintPage event, try adjusting the DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea to fit the image to the page. Here's a modified version of your PrintPage event:

doc.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
{
    System.Drawing.Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

    // Set the printable area to fit the entire page
    doc.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, m.Width, m.Height);

    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
};

Comment: @UsmanMehmood PrintableArea is read only?

Comment: You can produce PDF from any Windows printing application with [LEADTOOLS ePrint Professional](https://eprintdriver.com/Products/ePrint-Professional) printer driver. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). Try to print directly without converting to image first, but even if you print images that contain text, you can still get text in the output PDF because ePrint has built-in OCR. If you'd like to try it, download the free evaluation edition from [this page](https://eprintdriver.com/Download). If you need assistance, there's free email support during the evaluation period and after purchasing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the image conversion step and print the grid directly to a PDF, you can use MigraDoc and PdfSharp. First, make sure you have the necessary references and imports for these libraries.

```
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;

public void PrintGridToPdf(Grid datagrid, string filePath)
{
    // Create a PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Title = "Purchase Order";

    // Create a PDF page
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    // Measure the size of the grid
    Size gridSize = new Size((int)datagrid.ActualWidth, (int)datagrid.ActualHeight);

    // Render the grid to the PDF page
    XImage image = RenderToImage(datagrid, gridSize);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // Save the PDF document to the specified file
    document.Save(filePath);
}

private XImage RenderToImage(UIElement element, Size size)
{
    // Render the UI element to a bitmap
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap(size.Width, size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderTarget.Render(element);

    // Convert the bitmap to an XImage (PDF image)
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return XImage.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

You can call PrintGridToPdf with your grid and the desired file path to create the PDF directly from the grid without converting to an image.

PrintGridToPdf(datagrid, "path/to/save/purchase_order.pdf");